# Combining multiple data frames in a folder with varying column names

Tags: r

I have number of large data frames, with each row having a unique ID and each data frame could have different sets of column names (some are the same and some are not). I would like to have all of the data frames collated into a single data frame. I am currently using the `smartbind` function in `gtools` to bind together small data frames such as those in the example in below (and the output is what I require).

```
df1 <- data.frame("ID" = c(1,2,3))
df1$A <- c(1, 2, 3)
df1$B <- c("a", "d", "g")
df1


df2 <- data.frame("ID" = c(7,9,10))
df2$A <- c(5, 6, 7)
df2$C <- c("f", "bv", "gn")
df2


df3 <- data.frame("ID" = c(11,12,13))
df3$A <- c("g", "h", 7)
df3$B <- c("f", "bv", "gn")
df3$D <- c(1, 5, 7)
df3

gtools::smartbind(df1,df2,df3)

    ID A    B    C  D
1:1  1 1    a <NA> NA
1:2  2 2    d <NA> NA
1:3  3 3    g <NA> NA
2:1  7 5 <NA>    f NA
2:2  9 6 <NA>   bv NA
2:3 10 7 <NA>   gn NA
3:1 11 g    f <NA>  1
3:2 12 h   bv <NA>  5
3:3 13 7   gn <NA>  7
```

Although this is a good solution, it is fairly manual process (and I have read that smartbind is not ideal for large data frames?). I would like to ideally have code which would allow me to bind multiple .csv files in a folder. I currently have code which joins multiple .csv files in a folder (below), but this is a solution for joining multliple data frames and not a solution for binding multiple large data frames which have different sets of column names.

Below is the code I am using to merge multiple files in a folder:

```
data_all <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/Documents/path/",     
                       pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE) %>% 
            lapply(readr::read_csv) 

merged_files <- data_all %>% purrr::reduce(full_join, by = "ID")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `do.call` to combine list of dataframes using `smartbind`.

```
do.call(gtools::smartbind, data_all)
```

`smartbind` doesn't require classes of column of the same type and it changes the class implicitly.

---

If you convert the classes explicitly, you can also do this using `tidyverse` functions.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map_df(data_all, ~.x %>% mutate(across(-1, as.character)))

#  ID A    B    C    D
#1  1 1    a <NA> <NA>
#2  2 2    d <NA> <NA>
#3  3 3    g <NA> <NA>
#4  7 5 <NA>    f <NA>
#5  9 6 <NA>   bv <NA>
#6 10 7 <NA>   gn <NA>
#7 11 g    f <NA>    1
#8 12 h   bv <NA>    5
#9 13 7   gn <NA>    7
```